# Logging raw XML for generated CXF client

Tags: java, web-services, apache, logging, cxf

I have a ws-client generated using `wsdl2java` tool.
How do I log raw XML? 
Enabling `log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=DEBUG, CXF` in `log4j.properties` shows only useless debug info. But I can see that in uses interceptors, how do I install mine?

There are plenty of examples how to do it for server-side but I'd like to have it on client.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a sample project which logs on both sides. Sources can be found here: https://github.com/zjor/cxf-logging-raw-xml